# eclipse dynamic web project jsf http 404 error

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, http-status-code-404

My project will get a 404 when run on apache tomcat 6 server. localhost8080 works fine as I get tomcat homepage. my xhtml files are within my webcontent folder, and i believe my web.xml is set up correctly.

here are the files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Xperiment</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

experiment

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:outputLabel value="Ontology #{ontologyBean.name}"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns = "2">
                <h:outputText value="Experiment ID"></h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{experimentBean.ID}"></h:outputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns = "2">
                <h:outputText value="Experiment Name"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{experimentBean.name}"></h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns = "2">
                <h:outputText value="Experiment Description"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{experimentBean.description}"></h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns = "2">
                <h:outputText value="Experiment Date"></h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{experimentBean.date}"></h:outputText>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="create" action="#{experimentBean.setAOT}"/>

            <h:panelGrid rendered="#{experimentBean.addObjective}" columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Objective Description"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{experimentBean.EOD}"></h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton rendered="#{experimentBean.addObjective}" value="add" action="#{experimentBean.addAction}"/>

            <h:dataTable value="#{experimentBean.EOList}" var="eo">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Objective ID</f:facet>
                    #{eo.ID}        
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Objective Description</f:facet>
                    #{eo.description}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Objective Met</f:facet>
                    #{eo.met}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{experimentBean.deleteAction}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{experimentBean.EO}" value="#{eo}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
</html>
```

login

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.name}"></h:inputText>
                    <h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}"></h:inputSecret>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton value="Login" action="login"></h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
    </html>
```

welcome

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

        <h:outputLabel value="Welcome #{loginBean.name}"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns = "3">
                <h:outputText value="Ontology Name"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{ontologyBean.name}"></h:inputText>
                <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{ontologyBean.addAction}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:dataTable value="#{ontologyBean.ontologyList}" var="o">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Ontology Name</f:facet>
                    #{o.name}

                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="Start" action="experiment"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{ontologyBean.deleteAction}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ontologyBean.ontology}" value="#{o}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! Had to delete old workspace, make a new one and recreate project. Bothersome but it works!